# Cocos2d-x and ndk version

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I downloaded the latest cocos2d-x-3.12, but things didn't turn out to work when I got latest version of ndk.
My question what versions of cocos2d-x and ndk should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments in this post:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-v3-12-released/30641/70

cocos2d-x 3.12 should work with ndk r11+ specifically the r11c version.

and for more informations you can check the build requirements for cc2d-x 3.12 in here:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x#build-requirements